# Compiz disables 3rd Monitor

Tags: 11.04, compiz, ati

I have a try monitor setup with using the proprietary ATI drivers:

[image]

This works pretty well *with metacity*, with the exception of some maximize strangeness. On monitors 3 and 2 it works as expected. However, if maximize a window while it is with monitor 1 it maximizes on monitor 3. So I figured I would try Compiz.

When I start compiz with `compiz --replace` monitor 1 (forgive the backward numbering) goes black. The monitor does not lose power. I can still see the cursor if I move my mouse over to it, however compiz will not let me drag any windows to monitor 1.

I tried to set my outputs in ComizConfig Settings Manager but it doesn't seem to make a difference:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `Detect Outputs` checked, that overrides the manual outputs in the window below. Once I unchecked `Detect Outputs`, everything works well.

Comment: I saw the problem in the process of writing out this question, but figured it might help someone else.